# Why my word2vec training has not INFO printing

Tags: python

I'm a very beginner of the word2vec model. I use the following code to train a word2vec model.

```py
def Model_training(year):
    
    print("Loading Training Sample")
    training_sample_file = "training_sample_for_year" + str(year) +".csv"
    training_sample = pd.read_csv(training_sample_file).iloc[:,1:]



    print("PreTreating Training Sample")
    
    
    df_item1a = training_sample[~training_sample['item1a_textstemmed'].isna()]
    
    sent1a = [row.split() for row in df_item1a['item1a_textstemmed']]
    
    
    # initializing the model
    print("Model Initializing")

    w2v_model_1a = Word2Vec(
                         vector_size=3000,
                     
                         alpha=0.03, 
                         min_alpha=0.0007,
                            
                         
                         workers=15
                           )
    
    
    print("Vocabulary Building")
    
    w2v_model_1a.build_vocab(sent1a, progress_per=100)

    #train models
    print("Training Item1a Model")
    w2v_model_1a.train(sent1a, total_examples=len(sent1a), epochs=30)
    
    # capture model with no further changes
    
    print("Saving Models")
    w2v_model_1a.init_sims(replace=True)
    
    
    # save model
    model1a_name = "word2vecM_item1a_forYear" + str(year)+".model"
    w2v_model_1a.save(model1a_name)
   


for year in range(2007,2011):
    print("Now working on traing sample of year: ", year)
    Model_training(year)
```

For all the example online, I notice there will always be a INFO output while training for each epoch. Like the following image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANoqe.png)

However, my code only returns with the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Pz5.png)

How can I make the INFO show up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Those log messages appear every 10,000 sentences.  Do you have more than 10,000 sentences?

Comment: The 10,000 sentences is a default setting? Because the first time I train the mode, there are log messages. Only this morning, I rerun the code for the same dataset, the massages disappear...